# how to save value in prperties in place of session?

Tags: asp.net

I an using Session for storing UserName for whole project.
But it always time out before 20 min.
I want set value in properties and want to use in project but when my page is loading again its showing null value.

How can i save this value in  this?

Code what i am using.

```
public string UserName {get; set; }
public string Password {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties are a language construct (not an ASP.NET feature) and won't survive either.

You should persist the information in a database or up the session timeout.

Answer (score 0):

With a `public string UserName {get; set;}` you don't set anything in the Session.
Use this instead:

```
public string UserName
{
   get { return Session["UserName"] as string; }
   set { Session["UserName"] = value; }
}
```

Comment: but it will timeout after 20 min i want to increase this.

Comment: Then you will have to increase the session timeout or use ajax to keep the session alive as long as the user has the page open.
Cookies and viewstate are not an option for usernames and passwords.